# JSP page in a Coldfusion application not working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion application.
I wrote a simple JSP  page

```
<html>
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>   
<body>
     <% double num=1 %>
    num=<%= num %>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I call it, JSP is not understood...I get raw code:

```
<% double num=1 %> num=<%= num %>
```

It's a standard Coldfusion 11 installation running in Apache/Tomcat.

I forgot everytinhg about JSP, it should be some basic configuration at server level, any help welcome

Comment: How exactly do you call it?  Also, if you have a ColdFusion application, why are you writing JSP pages?

Comment: I call it simply as http://myapplication.com/test.jsp And I really need to understand how to integrate the 2 technologies because of legacy code and refactoring

Comment: Did you compile the jsp page?

Comment: (Edit) Normally, jsp files are compiled automatically. Where is the physical file located? I placed the above in a file named 'test.jsp', directly under the CF web root. It works fine with CF11 Express - after correcting the syntax error. The assignment is missing a semi-colon at the end, ie <% double num=1; %> num=<%= num %>

Comment: This https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/interoperating-with-jsp-pages-and-servlets.html should help you.